# How can I store audio and video files with phpMyAdmin

Tags: javascript, php, sql, database

So my original plan was to store images and audio in the directory with my html, css etc. but when I went to write my js, I found out I couldn't use `require(fs)`(I need to be able to search for these things) which threw a loop in my plan. My backup plan is to create a phpMyAdmin database to store my audio and images. I'm not sure how I could do this, or if it's even possible. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks so much.

Edit: I realized it might be possible to alter my Javascript so it does work so here it is.

```
const fs=require('fs')
var files = []
fs.readdir("Assets/Cards", (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(f_name => {
    files.push(f_name);
  });
})
console.log(files)
```

Answer (score -2):

Just save the media in the database in a column like media_content (it being varchar of course)
Just do something like

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

if this doesn't work try rebooting your server (this only works on linux and WINDOWS NT 5.1 or lower)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm on a mac. Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: This answer does not address the OP's question of how to properly handle media storage in a db environment.